# i want to read the serial port using arduino and want to save in excel in row & clumn??IndentationError:

Tags: python-2.7, csv, serial-port

```
import csv
import sys
import serial
import time

ser= serial.Serial('COM3', baudrate = 9600, timeout = 1)
time.sleep(3)

dataFile = open('NdataFile.csv','w') 

while ser.read():
    arduinoData = ser.readline().encode('HEX')
    if "\n" in arduinoData:
        dataFile.write("\n")
    else:
        dataFile.write(arduinoData + "\t")

ser.close()
```

Comment: Use this http://www.cleancss.com/python-beautify/  website to format your python code